# How to you get the "Share with Google Drive" contextual menu option in Finder?

Tags: finder, google-apps

Google Drive is installed but there is no option "View with Google Drive" or "Share with Google Drive" when I Control-click / Right-click on an item in the Finder like my coworkers have. How do you enable them?

Answer (score 9):

You need to enable the Finder extension Google Drive.

Open the contextual menu for any file, and click on Share and then More.

[image]

That will bring you to the Extensions window.

Click on Finder and in the "Select extensions for customizing Finder" select Google Drive.

[image]

Now you should see the "View in Google Drive" and "Share with Google Drive" options when you Control-click / secondary click on files inside your Google Drive.

[image]

Comment: This used to work but no longer does now that I've upgraded the OS to Mojave. I'm bummed that I am now missing this option (used it extensively). When I look at the contextual menus options google drive is an option in all BUT the share one.

Comment: Don't forget to restart the finder afterwards with pressing ALT + RESTART on the doc icon

Comment: For me this was listed as "Backup and Sync from Google".

Answer (score 3):

I also find that I need to occasionally uncheck, save, then recheck the checkbox "Show file sync status icons and right-click menu". This is found in the Backup and Sync settings menu.

[image: Backup and Sync settings]

Comment: Did you manage to find out how to automate that? Or the reason why this happens?

Comment: Neither of the solutions works for me on macOS Big Sur (M1).

Comment: This worked for me on Big Sur, 2017 Macbook Pro. Untick, click 'OK', then go back in and tick again.

Answer (score 1):

Quitting and re-launching the Google Drive app worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

everyone!

RubenLaguna's solution works actually. Despite of that I could test that on MacOS 10.13.6 (the well-know High Sierra). On High Sierra, after you get in Extensions settings, you'll not be able to find Google Drive.

A solution is simply open your Backup and Synch app, relaunch the Finder (ALT + right click on Finder then press "relaunch"). After that, you'll be able to see sharing Google Drive options after right clicking on any folder/file in Finder.

Cheers.