# How to save files to Google Drive in Finder?

Tags: macos, finder, google-apps

I read a previous post on this topic: "How to you get the “Share with Google Drive” contextual menu option in Finder?" 
[How to you get the "Share with Google Drive" contextual menu option in Finder?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/284685/how-to-you-get-the-share-with-google-drive-contextual-menu-option-in-finder)

I followed the steps indicated in your response, but I got stuck at step 3 because "Finder" is missing from my the Extension Menu. I use a MacBook Pro.
Kindly advise.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you provide a screen shot of your extension menu?

Answer (score 1):

The Google Drive is located at the root level on your mac. You could just use Spotlight to open the Google Drive folder and move or copy files directly to it. Or just go up levels in the Finder until you get to the root directory.

In my Finder sidebar window, under Devices, I have Macintosh HD as one of the devices. Clicking on this takes tou directly to the root directory. There you should see Google Drive.

Or you can use "Save As" and go up several levels until you see your Google Drive folder and save your file there.